# 4:3 - 16:9 Aspect Ratio Conversion with Pillarbox and Textbox

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-editor, conversion, aspect

I'm trying to use FFMpeg to adapt 4:3 (SD) to 16:9 (HD) and reverse function.

1. When SD is converted to HD, I need to add pillarboxes around the content.
2. When HD is converted to SD, I need to add textboxes.
3. Reverse of 1, I need to remove the pillarbox to convert to SD.
4. Reverse of 2, I need to remove the textbox to convert to HD.

For 1, I already found a solution:

```
ffmpeg -i input43.mp4 -vf "scale=640x480,setsar=1,pad=854:480:107:0" out43HD.mp4
```

But what are the commands to do 2, 3, and 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A small bit on terminology :- SD and HD refers to resolution - in the basic sense of the word, not dimensions. A given video can be wide or tall or square while being SD or HD. It's the legacy of television broadcast standards that SD content is 4:3 and HD 16:9 but display aspect ratio and visual definition aren't connected. That nitpick aside..

For 4:3 to 16:9 and back.

```
ffmpeg -i input43.mp4 -vf "scale=iw*sar:ih,setsar=1,pad=ih*16/9:ih:(ow-iw)/2:0" out43in169.mp4

ffmpeg -i out43in169.mp4 -vf "crop=ih*4/3:ih" backto43.mp4
```

For 16:9 to 4:3 and back.

```
ffmpeg -i input169.mp4 -vf "scale=iw*sar:ih,setsar=1,pad=iw:iw*3/4:0:(oh-ih)/2" out169in43.mp4

ffmpeg -i out169in43.mp4 -vf "crop=iw:iw*9/16" backto169.mp4
```

The crop filter automatically crops from the center of the input frame so it's not necessary to specify the x and y offsets. Audio is transcoded, always. Add `-c:a copy` to avoid that.

Comment: Thanks. Video has to be encoded anyways, right? We can not use `-c:v copy`?

Comment: Btw, does ffmpeg use multi-threading by default? I'm thinking how we can make it run faster. How about running on GPU?!

Comment: FFmpeg does processing in multiple threads where possible.

Comment: `-c:v copy` is not possible here.

Comment: this is ok for 1 shot encoding when you eyeball control your input, in any batch stuff you should cropdetect first (https://www.nab.org/documents/resources/paperTandberg.pdf) and use logic for correct cropping/scaling the area of interest depending on your i/o dar, it can be quite pain in the butt in fact to automate it in a bulletproof way...